Communicate with chrome extension from react web page error
I tried to send data from React web page to my extension to check if the extension is allowed in  incognito mode or not. I was using chrome.runtime.sendMessage, and it worked correctly:
React web app:
  useEffect(() => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('my_extension_id', { check: 'checkIncognito' }, (response) => {
      if (response.checkIncognito) {
        // handle logic
      } else {
        ...
      }
    });
  }, []);

background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  chrome.extension.isAllowedIncognitoAccess(async (isAllowedAccess) => {
    if (request?.check === 'checkIncognito' && isAllowedAccess) {
      sendResponse({ checkIncognito: true });
    } else {
      sendResponse({ checkIncognito: false });
    }
  });
});

But I have a case where, when I had some extensions (e.g. katalon: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid), I cannot use sendMessage to my extension anymore, and it throws the error: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
I have tried to log chrome.runtime to check in my React app. When I haven't downloaded Katalon, the chrome.runtime still has the sendMessage function. But when I download Katalon, chrome.runtime returns the Proxy(Function) {length: 0, name: ''}. I haven't found any documentation about this chrome.runtime behavior.
Is there any way to fix this, or another way to communicate from my React app to my extension? Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!
